# kernel PCA with Kernlab r , out of memory error

Tags: r, kernel, pca

trying to apply kernel PCA with Kernlab in r on 12*250,000 data set

```
 kpc <- kpca(~.,csv.data,kernel="rbfdot",kpar=list(sigma=0.2),features=2)
```

getting the bellow error

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 604.1 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In crossprod(t(x)) :
  Reached total allocation of 16305Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In crossprod(t(x)) :
  Reached total allocation of 16305Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In crossprod(t(x)) :
  Reached total allocation of 16305Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In crossprod(t(x)) :
  Reached total allocation of 16305Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

Any suggestion how can i manage to run this algorithm on such large data set?

Thanks.

Comment: Couple obvious solutions: 1) If there is any meaningful way to filter out some subset of rows/columns, or split the data into subsets (e.g. known subgroups), you can try doing that to reduce the data size, 2) random subsampling.

Comment: tried to reduce the data set to be 12*75,000 still getting the same exception
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 41.2 Gb
In addition: Warning messages

this function can't recive such data set, seems starnge